# How can I "spread" a form to two areas of a Bootstrap panel? (Browser "fixing" unclosed form tag)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

For layout major reasons I want to have two parts of a form in different parts of the page.

At the top I have:

```
<form  name="formXYZ" method="post" action="client-edit-transmission.php">
    <textarea  class="form-control input-sm" name="content" id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo "$content"?></textarea>
    <input name="userName" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$userName"; ?>">
```

etc. This is in the top part of a Bootstrap panel. It is the message that will be sent out at various times

In the panel body I have all the possible times the messages can be sent. Sun - Sat, week of the month 1-5. IE 35 `<input type="text` fields generated by a php foreach loop pulling down the individual times and ids from a DB. Viz five times:

```
<tr>
<?php echo ("<td> $localDay  </td>"); // $dayScheduleId
//For each time schedule get time
                foreach ($timeSchedule as $timeItem) { 
echo "<td>";
                    $localTime = $mySchedule->retrieveTime ($timeItem);
                    debug($localTime,"hola");
                    $localTime = $mySchedule->dirtyTime ($localTime);
                  ///////////////////////////////////    NB 5 TIMES A WEEK TIME TAB   ?>
<input name="time_id<?php echo"$timeItem"?>" id="time_id_id<?php echo"$timeItem"?>" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:55px; height:20px; margin:0; padding:2px;  text-align: center;" type="text" value="<?php echo"$localTime"?>">
<?php echo "</td>";
         } 
 echo "</tr>";
```

Originally I had two separate forms but when a user sees the page it is all too tempting to edit the text and then go down the page and edit the times. If you hit the top submit button the message is updated and not the times and the bottom button vice versa. Very unhelpful.

I cleaned everything out and made one big form BUT did not realise that Chrome (and I presume other browsers) inset a `</form>` tag if you try and push the form past a `</div>`. I presume they are kindly fixing unclosed tags.

I have tried naming the forms the same but that does not work. The top part of the form is very simple - just a text area whose value is populated by a php `echo`. My JS is rudimentary and jQuery just about non existent. If there is not a straight HTML way through this is there a SIMPLE JS solution (and/or PHP)?

Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Move the `<form>` tag itself up in the DOM so it becomes a common ancestor for both parts of the form?

Comment: Looks like that might be a solution - thanks. Form not updating message but suspect that is a normal screw up. But no unwelcome inserted `</form>` tags. Thanks. Off to debug.

Comment: I apologize for being unbelievably dense but I am doing something wrong here:`<textarea  class="form-control input-sm" name="content" id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo "$content"?></textarea>` The `_POST` reports `["content"]=>
  string(4) "This"` no matter what I put in the text area. IE the text area always says just "This"! This was working. Any thoughts on what I have done? PS have moved the text field in with all the other fields to test this.

Comment: Check if you have more fields with the same name - does `jQuery('[name="content"]')` find only the textarea or more fields?

Comment: Feck me you are good! Not using jQuery but had a hidden field when it was two forms to pass through the value of the content field. Cannot thank you enough. Guess I am on babysitting duty for you for the next five years. OK finishing for the night. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by simply passing a hidden field.